# Safe countries for touring (without having to take public trasport all the time) in EU?

Tags: safety, touring

I discussed today foreign ambulance guys and they told stories about sliced bicyclists in an  ex-communist country. The country in itself is not special but rather the fact that it lacks proper roads for cars, it then again means that it is blatantly dangerous ride the zig-zag roads along with 100km/h speed limits or more that are not even designed for such speeds.

So I want to gather here countries that do not have such problems. I planned my road along such zig-zag road with Google Maps but after hearing the story and seeing the conditions, I decided to get a local bus over the dangerous area.

Before I continue towards South, I would like to know which countries to avoid inside EU.

**Resources**

1. European Long-distance-paths [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_long-distance_paths)
2. European Cyclists Federation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Cyclists%27_Federation), some paths suggested
3. Some research done from [Europe](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=bicycle+roads+europe)

**Related questions**

1. political aspect and safety in long-distance bicycling [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4245/which-counties-should-be-avoided-due-to-political-reasons)
2. evolution of bicycle infrastructure, trying to investigate how/why bicycle infrastructure evolves [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/how-do-bicycle-infrastructure-evolve)

Comment: Bike planes? Do you mean bike lanes?

Comment: @HH01 - Are you asking about countries "worldwide"? Or are you limiting your question to European countries? Also within a particular country, there can be regions that are very bike friendly, yet other regions that are not. If your question is limited to Europe, I would suggest adding the regional tag.

Comment: I voted to close. The question is so open-ended and subjective as to be impossible to answer.

Comment: I agree with wdypdx22, this question is far too open-ended, and I've closed it. @HH01, would be happy to re-open if you can narrow this down some. Right now, this isn't asking a specific question, it's inviting a discussion, something Stack Exchange isn't built for.

Comment: @Ambo100 - Mmmmaybe. Wanna bring it up in meta, maybe with a proposed edit? I'd like to hear what folks have to say about it, specifically including hhh, the OP.

Comment: @Ambo100: thank you for the point, please, answer your question [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/4245/652) about politics/law and bicycle safety (I try to keep this question more focused, better to create more focused questions).

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question to answer.

Is London better because it has lots of official bike lanes, bike stop signs and bike crossings? But it also has a huge amount of traffic and lots of heavy trucks and busses in small streets.

Cambridge has little official support for bikes (it periodically bans them from areas of the city) but because there is relatively little traffic and a lot of bikes it's pretty good to cycle in.